# How to assign row values as 0 if row names do not match another dataframe?

Tags: r

The list of dataframe `df.list` contains 6 dataframes with same number of columns but different number of rows.

I want all the dataframes to have the same number of rows. If the rowname is not in the dataframe (i.e., unique), assign the values as 0. The dataframes should be returned individually (not in a list).

```
df.list <- list(scores.1a, scores.1b, scores.1c, scores.2a, scores.2b, scores.2c)
unique.names <- Reduce(unique, lapply(df.list, row.names))

notin1a <- scores.1a[!(rownames(scores.1a) %in% unique.names),] 
scores.1a <- rbind(scores.1a, notin1a)
notin1b <- scores.1b[!(rownames(scores.1b) %in% unique.names),] 
scores.1b <- rbind(scores.1b, notin1b)
notin1c <- scores.1c[!(rownames(scores.1c) %in% unique.names),] 
scores.1c <- rbind(scores.1c, notin1c)
notin2a <- scores.2a[!(rownames(scores.2a) %in% unique.names),] 
scores.2a <- rbind(scores.2a, notin2a)
notin2b <- scores.2b[!(rownames(scores.2b) %in% common.names),] 
scores.2b <- rbind(scores.2b, notin2b)
notin2c <- scores.2c[!(rownames(scores.2c) %in% unique.names),] 
scores.2c <- rbind(scores.2c, notin2c)
```

Traceback:

```
Error in cbind(scores.1a, scores.1b, scores.1c, scores.2a, scores.2b,  : 
  number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

Sample Data:

```
df.list <- list(
  matrix(
    rep(
      c(
        4.69416065754249e-42, 6.0513299332676e-38, 2.89877790887805e-36,
        2.85123238031875e-33, 1.47604844342483e-30, 3.43040504604337e-30,
        5.86872957403304e-29, 1.06954287499982e-28, 1.30662578944682e-28,
        4.82163948607124e-28
      ), 4
    ),
    nrow = 10L,
    ncol = 4L,
    dimnames = list(
      c(
        "A2M", "ABCA7", "ABCB9", "ABCD1", "ABLIM2", "ABT1", "ACAP1",
        "ACAP3", "ACCS", "ACOT9"
      ),
      c("KIRP1a.X3UTR", "KIRP1a.X5UTR", "KIRP1a.CDS", "KIRP1a.promCore")
    )
  ),
  matrix(
    rep(
      c(
        6.02781805188179e-32, 5.82900841856826e-27, 8.8650545387109e-26,
        2.61277026722025e-24, 6.24024734286127e-23, 8.77298331273884e-23,
        1.94852987224159e-22, 3.57104113334633e-22, 4.86000479954981e-22,
        6.49022377188339e-21
      ), 4
    ),
    nrow = 10L,
    ncol = 4L,
    dimnames = list(
      c(
        "A2M", "ABCA7", "ABCB9", "ABCD1", "ACAP1", "ACAP3", "ACCS",
        "ACRBP", "ACTB", "ACTN4"
      ),
      c("KIRP1b.X3UTR", "KIRP1b.X5UTR", "KIRP1b.CDS", "KIRP1b.promCore")
    )
  ),
  matrix(
    rep(
      c(
        1.55502961788497e-37, 6.82123433099474e-34, 2.16318121565099e-33,
        1.61437112767647e-32, 5.62718186736796e-29, 8.80498672474288e-29,
        1.40908074678065e-28, 1.0691910168236e-27, 2.45751770107637e-27,
        3.51830046859091e-27
      ), 4
    ),
    nrow = 10L,
    ncol = 4L,
    dimnames = list(
      c(
        "A2M", "ABCA7", "ABCB9", "ABCD1", "ACAP1", "ACAP3", "ACCS",
        "ACOT9", "ACRBP", "ACTB"
      ),
      c("KIRP1c.X3UTR", "KIRP1c.X5UTR", "KIRP1c.CDS", "KIRP1c.promCore")
    )
  ),
  matrix(
    rep(
      c(
        4.62071070020255e-35, 1.01109404411977e-30, 1.62340375422632e-28,
        5.05748981709716e-27, 7.4566799068015e-26, 9.95551308236402e-26,
        1.22734181112028e-25, 1.3752043675869e-25, 5.33041187027489e-25,
        6.3150904604211e-25
      ), 4
    ),
    nrow = 10L,
    ncol = 4L,
    dimnames = list(
      c(
        "A2M", "ABCA7", "ABCB9", "ABCD1", "ABLIM2", "ABT1", "ACAP1",
        "ACCS", "ACOX3", "ACRBP"
      ),
      c("KIRP2a.X3UTR", "KIRP2a.X5UTR", "KIRP2a.CDS", "KIRP2a.promCore")
    )
  ),
  matrix(
    rep(
      c(
        9.74240010701507e-40, 2.11789902281316e-33, 4.46523408292594e-31,
        1.30189496759334e-30, 1.02042844284013e-29, 1.99943105322521e-29,
        3.00065886399859e-29, 3.51759154868364e-29, 1.0237124789762e-28,
        1.66731834926145e-28
      ), 4
    ),
    nrow = 10L,
    ncol = 4L,
    dimnames = list(
      c(
        "A2M", "ABCA7", "ABCB9", "ABCD1", "ABT1", "ACAP1", "ACAP3",
        "ACCS", "ACOX3", "ACRBP"
      ),
      c("KIRP2b.X3UTR", "KIRP2b.X5UTR", "KIRP2b.CDS", "KIRP2b.promCore")
    )
  ),
  matrix(
    rep(
      c(
        2.77090056563127e-28, 1.21015896726265e-25, 1.84118490393544e-25,
        4.65592701166262e-25, 3.26614231027095e-23, 6.1338391921814e-23,
        3.31888253251873e-22, 1.55135657676455e-21, 3.98472400556953e-20,
        6.56496181862045e-20
      ), 4
    ),
    nrow = 10L,
    ncol = 4L,
    dimnames = list(
      c(
        "ABCA7", "ABCB9", "ABCD1", "ACAP1", "ACRBP", "ACTB", "ACYP2",
        "ADAMTS3", "ADAMTS7", "ADAMTSL4"
      ),
      c("KIRP2c.X3UTR", "KIRP2c.X5UTR", "KIRP2c.CDS", "KIRP2c.promCore")
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: `df.list` is a list of matrices, not a list of data frames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've simplified the example to make the result more obvious, but this will also work on your full data. Since you are actually working with a list of `matrix` objects, I convert to a `data.frame` and then assign the missing rows in each set to 0.

Example data:

```
mat <- matrix(1:9, nrow=3, dimnames=list(letters[1:3], LETTERS[1:3]))
df.list <- list(mat[c(1,2),], mat[c(1,3),], mat[c(2,3),])

#[[1]]
#  A B C
#a 1 4 7
#b 2 5 8
#
#[[2]]
#  A B C
#a 1 4 7
#c 3 6 9
#
#[[3]]
#  A B C
#b 2 5 8
#c 3 6 9
```

Process it:

```
allrn <- Reduce(union, lapply(df.list, rownames))
df.list <- lapply(
    df.list,
    \(x) {
        x <- as.data.frame(x)
        x[setdiff(allrn, rownames(x)),] <- 0
        x[order(rownames(x)),]
    }
)

df.list
#[[1]]
#  A B C
#a 1 4 7
#b 2 5 8
#c 0 0 0
#
#[[2]]
#  A B C
#a 1 4 7
#b 0 0 0
#c 3 6 9
#
#[[3]]
#  A B C
#a 0 0 0
#b 2 5 8
#c 3 6 9
```

Answer (score 2):

You could first find the max rows of all the data frames in the list, then use `lapply` to add rows (up until the max) containing 0's across all columns using indexing.

Using simplified data for easier illustration:

```
ll <- list(data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 1:3),
           data.frame(a = 1:7, b = 1:7))
```

You can do this by:

```
maxrows <- max(unlist(lapply(ll, nrow)))

ll_same <- lapply(ll, function(x){if(nrow(x) < maxrows) x[(nrow(x)+1):maxrows,] <- 0; x})
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
  a b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 0 0
5 0 0
6 0 0
7 0 0

[[2]]
  a b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5
6 6 6
7 7 7
```

If you want each df in the list to be its own object in the environment, use `assign`:

```
# assign each df in the list to the environment
for(i in seq_along(ll_same)){
  assign(paste0("df_", i), ll_same[[i]])
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your attempt. I added something: The dataframes should be returned individually (not in a list).

Comment: @melolili - there is no reason to do that. It's a bad idea™ as the list is a lot easier to work with using `lapply` then it is to have 6 separate datasets floating around that you need to reference individually.

Comment: @melolili I agree with thelatemail - lists are generally preferred, though see edit to return the individual dfs to the environment if desired. To each their own

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using `match` and `replace`.

```
uniq_rownames <- unique(as.vector(sapply(df.list, rownames)))

lapply(df.list, function(x){
  res <- x[match(uniq_rownames, rownames(x)),]
  res <- replace(res, is.na(rownames(res)), 0)
  data.frame(res, row.names=uniq_rownames)})
[[1]]
         KIRP1a.X3UTR KIRP1a.X5UTR   KIRP1a.CDS KIRP1a.promCore
A2M      4.694161e-42 4.694161e-42 4.694161e-42    4.694161e-42
ABCA7    6.051330e-38 6.051330e-38 6.051330e-38    6.051330e-38
ABCB9    2.898778e-36 2.898778e-36 2.898778e-36    2.898778e-36
ABCD1    2.851232e-33 2.851232e-33 2.851232e-33    2.851232e-33
ABLIM2   1.476048e-30 1.476048e-30 1.476048e-30    1.476048e-30
ABT1     3.430405e-30 3.430405e-30 3.430405e-30    3.430405e-30
ACAP1    5.868730e-29 5.868730e-29 5.868730e-29    5.868730e-29
ACAP3    1.069543e-28 1.069543e-28 1.069543e-28    1.069543e-28
ACCS     1.306626e-28 1.306626e-28 1.306626e-28    1.306626e-28
ACOT9    4.821639e-28 4.821639e-28 4.821639e-28    4.821639e-28
ACRBP    0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
ACTB     0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
ACTN4    0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
ACOX3    0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
ACYP2    0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
ADAMTS3  0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
ADAMTS7  0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
ADAMTSL4 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00

[[2]]
         KIRP1b.X3UTR KIRP1b.X5UTR   KIRP1b.CDS KIRP1b.promCore
A2M      6.027818e-32 6.027818e-32 6.027818e-32    6.027818e-32
ABCA7    5.829008e-27 5.829008e-27 5.829008e-27    5.829008e-27
ABCB9    8.865055e-26 8.865055e-26 8.865055e-26    8.865055e-26
...
```